# Install graphic driver in 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

I just install Ubuntu in my desktop (Which has nvidia card 750TI and CPU i5 with HD4000), now i don't know how to install driver in right way (i followed some instructors on internet but still dont work in my computer). Now my screen resolution is 640x480, I used to use the 1980x1080 in windows 8. 
So, can somebody tell me the way to fix that problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you asking this question.But there are two options:

1.You only have to press the ***super key*** and type *additional drivers*. Then click on the icon of the **additional drivers** program
and scan for drivers. It will automatically show you the available drivers.
2.Go to the graphics engine website (nvidia.com/amd.com) and download the driver.

Comment: and if there are no proprietary drivers in use?